# What is the actual value of a reference variable in java?

Tags: java, pointers, reference, jvm

I read a lot of articles regarding this subject and I really want to understand what is the value that it's stored inside a reference variable in java. There are just too many opinions for such a basic question.
It's not clear for me it's just the physical memory address(but we can't access it or manage it) or it's another value that JVM use it to recognise the object(I saw a lot of times the "handler" word)?
I know that the implementation may depend on the java/JVM version

Is there any version of java/JVM where references are implemented as memory addresses? Or maybe in all of them ?

Comment: Kind of, I really understand the concept but it's so confusing that, let's say you pass the value of a reference into a function, now I don't really know what value I pass, I just know that the function variable now points to the same object. I want to know that there is a memory address or another value interpreted later by the JVM

Comment: You can think of it as an address in memory, the number of the first octet of memory where the content of that object (its state, and references to methods defined in the class) lives. For [memory safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_safety), a reference in Java is not literally a memory address. But you can think of it as that. And so, values in Java are [always pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/642706), not pass-by-reference. Passing a primitive passes its content: a number, a boolean, etc. Passing an object passes its content: our pretend memory address.

Comment: So inside the reference variable is stored an "intermediate" value that points to the actual address? Not the address itself? I understand that in developer perspective this change nothing, but I really want to know if it s stored the actual address or an intermediate value interpreted by the JVM to reference that object. Thanks!

Comment: With modern OSs' memory virtualization, there are no 'real' addresses anymore. Each program has its own linear RAM, starting at 0. The OS converts that address to the real location. That may be RAM or swap file or someplace even weirder. It gets even more complicated with Level x caches. So, Java reference variables, like any application on modern operating systems, point to that virtual address. And Java reference variables are only address values ("pointers") at runtime, but lots of metadata is stored someplace else, like for Garbage Collection etc. Every JVM and GC handles it differently.

Comment: So, on top of the RAM virtualization: In most JVMs, when the Garbage Collector runs a cycle, it needs to block off all access (pause threads) to the sector it's clearing up, then moves the memory contents, then updates all reference variables to point to the new location, then it can resume the threads. AND there are even other effects worth noting, like JVM's runtime optimization, mostly JIT-compilation, which AGAIN may change the behaviour of the JVM, how and where it loads Objects: stack, heap, permgen, metaspace, eden vs survivor memory, constant pools, just to throw in a few names...

Comment: P.S. The last sentence in my Comment was missing a crucial word: *reference*: Passing an object reference passes its content: our pretend memory address. (We never pass objects in Java; we pass object references.)

Comment: Early implementations used a handle which was a pointer to a pointer. Nowadays it’s more than often just a pointer (memory address) or the memory address divided by eight (when your heap size is >4GB and <32GB).

Comment: Ok, thanks for all, but what if the address of an object changes during GC? The reference variable will hold the same address?

Comment: Check out some articles explaining Garbage Collectors. Or read my last comment. It names the 4 basic steps most GCs need. I wrote that comment to hint at why for most reference variables (depending in which JVM space their target data lies) the JVM needs additional metadata stored or generated. Instead of going on here, why don't you read articles or specifications for the Java Memory Model? There are enough out there, and they will answer all your questions in detail.